# IOS/Objective-C: Type Enforcement for NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

If you save an integer as an NSUserDefault, it is possible to retrieve it as a string as well as a number?

```
//Set
[prefs setInteger:99 forKey:@"userid"];

//Get
NSNumber *useridnum =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userid"];//seems to work

NSString *userid =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userid"];//seems to work
```

I would have thought not but it seems to be possible unless I am missing something.

Thanks for any clarification on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

> Given a key that identifies an attribute or to-one relationship, return the attribute value or the related object. Given a key that identifies a to-many relationship, return an immutable array or an immutable set that contains all of the related objects.

```
- (nullable id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userid"]` will return an `id` type variable. You can assign it to whatever type you want. If you feel that is not safe, you can try to cast it to the type you want.

Comment: So I guess you can access it either way using valueForKey.  I guess if you want the string exclusively you say stringForKey as @dan suggests or if you want the integer you can use integerForKey

Answer (score 1):

Your `userid` string is actually an `NSNumber`, you're just lieing to the compiler and telling it that it is an `NSString`.  If you attempt to call a method on it that is on `NSString` but not `NSNumber` then it will crash at runtime.

You can, however, tell user defaults to retrieve the value as a string using the `stringForKey:` method and it will return an `NSString` even if you originally stored the value as an integer.

```
NSString *userid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userid"]; // actually a string
```

Comment: I am able to log to console both the string and number version.  And I can use the string version in NSString *pic = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@_pic.png", userid]; without crash.

Comment: That's because the %@ formatter only cares that you are passing it an `NSObject`, which `NSNumber` and `NSString` both satisfy.  Try calling `userid.length` and you will see the crash because `NSNumber` does not respond to `length`